# Error message when adding multiple radiobuttons in listview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a Listview with multiple radiobuttons added in each Listview position.
I have no idea how to do it and tried finding some solutions but neither of them worked.

This is my code.

```
public class Bouw_onderdeel extends Activity {
public String[] naam = {"Bouw onderdeel", "Kapconstructie","Kapconstructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Dakconstructie","Constructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Waterkerende lagen","Waterdichtheid (folie)laag","Lekwaterafvoerend vermogen","Detaillering aan dakvoet","Thermischeisolatie","Bevestiging","Aansluitdetails","Isolerend vermogen","Dakpannen en vorsten","Conditie dakpannen en vorsten","Breukschade","Vorstschade","Afschilfering","Aangroei algen en mos"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bouwonderdeel_layout);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutBouwonderdeel);  

    ListView list = new ListView(this);
    list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, naam));

    setContentView(list);

}
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] strings) {
        super(context, -1, -1, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LinearLayout listLayout = new LinearLayout(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        listLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        listLayout.setId(5000);
        RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton (Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        RadioGroup rbg = new RadioGroup(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        TextView listText = new TextView(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        listText.setId(5001);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            rbg.addView(rbtn);
        }
        listLayout.addView(rbg);
        listLayout.addView(listText);

    listText.setText(super.getItem(position));

        return listLayout;
    }
}
```

This is the error message.

```
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child        already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3739)
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3610)
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261):    at android.widget.RadioGroup.addView(RadioGroup.java:141)
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3555)
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3531)
10-27 15:25:19.495: E/AndroidRuntime(18261):    at nl.opensourcevoormkb.Bouw_onderdeel$MyAdapter.getView(Bouw_onderdeel.java:54)
```

Comment: probably because of you are adding same radio button try create the  rbtn in the loop and add the rbg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize RadioButtons inside the loop.

```
    RadioGroup rbg = new RadioGroup(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton (Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        rbg.addView(rbtn);
    }
```